# Removing JTable CellRenderer when radiobutton is deselected

Tags: java, jtable

I'm using the following code to apply a CellRender on my JTable password field

```
JRadioButton HidePW = new JRadioButton("Show Passwords ");
HidePW.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
         if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
             ConnectionsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(togglePW);
             ConnectionsTable.repaint();
          }else{

          };
     }
});
```

it is working great, however could someone help me not have this apply when the radio button becomes unselected? is there a simple way to overwrite this custom CellRender or remove it?

Comment: `have this apply when the radio button becomes unselected?` Get the CellRenderer of that Column before setting it to your custom render, and just set it back when the button is unselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` block apply the default cell renderer :

```
ConnectionsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(ConnectionsTable.
                                              getDefaultRenderer(String.class));
```